# remove duplicate from declared table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have created  a query in sql server 2008 when i run this query i found duplicates records i goggled for the solution to remove duplicates but i not found right answer

my query is

```
DECLARE @table_proposal TABLE (
            applicationno NVARCHAR(200)
           ,sname NVARCHAR(200)
           ,gender NVARCHAR(50)
           ,annual_income NVARCHAR(200)
           ,period NVARCHAR(200)
           ,monthly NVARCHAR(200)
           ,scholarshipamt NVARCHAR(200)
           ,book NVARCHAR(200)
           ,totalamt NVARCHAR(200)
           ,bank NVARCHAR(200)
           ,serialno NUMERIC(20)
        )

INSERT INTO @table_proposal
  (
    applicationno
   ,sname
   ,gender
   ,annual_income
   ,period
   ,monthly
   ,scholarshipamt
   ,book
   ,totalamt
   ,bank
   ,serialno
  )(
       SELECT tspr.student_code
             ,First_Name + ' ' + Middle_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS NAME
             ,Gender_Code
             ,tsam.Scholarship_Amount
             ,Academic_Year_Code
             ,tsam.Scholarship_Amount  AS monthly
             ,tsed.Scholarship_Amount
             ,tsam.Amount_for_books    AS book
             ,tsed.Scholarship_Amount
             ,'AC - ' + CAST(Account_No AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' / ' + Bank_Name
             ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tspr.student_code)
       FROM tbl_Student_Personal_Registration tspr
       INNER
       JOIN tbl_Student_Educational_Details tsed    ON  tspr.Student_Code = tsed.Student_Code
       INNER
       JOIN tbl_Proposal_Detail tpd ON  tpd.Student_Code = tspr.Student_Code 
       INNER JOIN   tbl_Scholarship_Amount_Master tsam  ON  tspr.Hotellers = 
       tsam.Hosteller
                   AND tsam.Gender = tspr.Gender_Code
                   AND tsam.Category_Code = tspr.Category_Code
       WHERE  tpd.Proposal_Id = 'N/1/CG0120G001/B/13/01'
   )
SELECT applicationno
      ,sname
      ,gender
      ,annual_income
      ,period
      ,monthly
      ,scholarshipamt
      ,book
      ,totalamt
      ,bank
      ,serialno
      ,COUNT(applicationno)
FROM    @table_proposal
GROUP BY
       applicationno
      ,sname
      ,gender
      ,annual_income
      ,period
      ,monthly
      ,scholarshipamt
      ,book
      ,totalamt
      ,bank
      ,serialno
```

Comment: Could you perhaps give sample/simplified dataset? Alos, it is important, when eliminating duplicates to illustrate which fields form the natural primary key (unique identifier) of the row.

Answer (score 0):

can you tried below query

```
DECLARE @table_proposal TABLE (
            applicationno NVARCHAR(200)
           ,sname NVARCHAR(200)
           ,gender NVARCHAR(50)
           ,annual_income NVARCHAR(200)
           ,period NVARCHAR(200)
           ,monthly NVARCHAR(200)
           ,scholarshipamt NVARCHAR(200)
           ,book NVARCHAR(200)
           ,totalamt NVARCHAR(200)
           ,bank NVARCHAR(200)
        )

INSERT INTO @table_proposal
  (
    applicationno
   ,sname
   ,gender
   ,annual_income
   ,period
   ,monthly
   ,scholarshipamt
   ,book
   ,totalamt
   ,bank
  )(
       SELECT tspr.student_code
             ,First_Name + ' ' + Middle_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS NAME
             ,Gender_Code
             ,tsam.Scholarship_Amount
             ,Academic_Year_Code
             ,tsam.Scholarship_Amount  AS monthly
             ,tsed.Scholarship_Amount
             ,tsam.Amount_for_books    AS book
             ,tsed.Scholarship_Amount
             ,'AC - ' + CAST(Account_No AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' / ' + Bank_Name

       FROM tbl_Student_Personal_Registration tspr
       INNER
       JOIN tbl_Student_Educational_Details tsed    ON  tspr.Student_Code = tsed.Student_Code
       INNER
       JOIN tbl_Proposal_Detail tpd ON  tpd.Student_Code = tspr.Student_Code 
       INNER JOIN   tbl_Scholarship_Amount_Master tsam  ON  tspr.Hotellers = 
       tsam.Hosteller
                   AND tsam.Gender = tspr.Gender_Code
                   AND tsam.Category_Code = tspr.Category_Code
       WHERE  tpd.Proposal_Id = 'N/1/CG0120G001/B/13/01'
   )
SELECT applicationno
      ,sname
      ,gender
      ,annual_income
      ,period
      ,monthly
      ,scholarshipamt
      ,book
      ,totalamt
      ,bank
      ,,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY applicationno) AS serialno
      ,COUNT(applicationno)
FROM    @table_proposal
GROUP BY
       applicationno
      ,sname
      ,gender
      ,annual_income
      ,period
      ,monthly
      ,scholarshipamt
      ,book
      ,totalamt
      ,bank
      ,serialno
```